# iOS App and Website syncing issues

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app

Official iOS app v0.1.44 bug:

Joined meta.stackoverflow since I got invited to the alpha testing group for iOS. Installed the app. Tried to do some upvoting/downvoting on the app, and it says I am not a member of the stack, and can't vote. I click "Join" and it gives me an error saying that I am already a member. Closing/opening app did not resolve. Total time elapsed: ~10 minutes. A log out/in did resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried again recently?  We're at 0.1.60 now and signup / login has been touched a lot.

Comment: I just tried it out again, and it worked instantly this time. I also got the notification of your comment immediately. Working great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response.  Like you noted in your comment, it looks like this has been fixed somewhere between 0.1.44 and 0.1.60.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Looks like it's back: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236960/registering-to-a-new-site-after-asking-a-question-is-broken-on-the-ios-app-versi.