# Registering to a new site after asking a question is broken on the iOS app version 1.1.0

Tags: bug, ios-app

After using the mobile app to ask a question on a new site (I didn't have an account there yet), the question was posted just fine, however when trying to add a comment on that question the app asks me to join the site (but I already did), and even if I try to join it a second time it fails (it'd be nice if it failed silently and just refreshed when it realized that I was already registered), see the following screenshots :

[image: join site dialog] [image: already a member error message]

Also the app seems to behave as if I wasn't registered there since I can't even edit my own question, despite having my account correctly created there and linked to my other accounts.

iOS version 7.1.2, app version 1.1.0 on iPhone 5S.

Comment: Happens in android app as well. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232070/login-issue-with-stack-exchange-android-app